# How to recursively call a function over the length of the list?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I had an interview question, and it has been bugging me since then.

I have a function, fill, that does the computation like taking two lists and then replacing 2s in the second list, where ever there are 2s in the first list and also once 2s are filled in the second list from the first list, then it can flow till a 1 is encountered. For eg:

Two lists `[2,1,2,1,2]` `[0,0,1,0,0]` is passed, so the output I get is `[2,2,1,2,2]`. Now, I want to write a function that takes an argument something like this: `[[2,1,2,1,2],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]`, I want to apply my above function recursively till the end of this list of lists. So like first `[2,1,2,1,2]` `[0,0,1,0,0]` are passed to fill, then it should get the result `[2,2,1,2,2]`, then `[2,2,1,2,2]` and `[0,0,0,0,0]` should be passed, getting the result `[2,2,2,2,2]`. How can I do that?

EDIT:

I did this:

```
fillAll::[[Int]]->[Int]
fillAll [] = []
fillAll (x:xs) =
  (foldl' seep x xs) $
  helper2 x


helper2:: [Int] -> Bool
helper2 lst = 
  if 2 `elem` lst then True else False
```

Comment: `helper2 [foldl' seep x xs]` desugars to `if foldl' seep x xs == 2 then True else False`, which is just `foldl' seep x xs == 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have your function `fill`:

```
fill :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

And you want to turn this into a function which takes a list of lists:

```
fillRec :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

This is a natural case for a fold. This repeatedly 'folds' each element of a list together using a combining function. We need to make sure the list isn't empty:

```
fillRec [] = []
fillRec (x : xs) = foldl fill x xs
```

This version of `foldl` (e.g. folds from the left, rather than from the right) is non-strict, which can cause large memory accumulation. It's better to use the strict variant `foldl'` from `Data.List`:

```
fillRec (x : xs) = foldl' fill x xs
```

Comment: Why don't you use `foldl1`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you already have `fill :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]` defined.  If so, this problem is pretty easy to solve using a `fold`.  Explicitly, you could do something like

```
fillAll :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
fillAll [] = []
fillAll (x:xs) = go x xs
    where
        go first [] = first
        go first (second:rest) = go (fill first second) rest
```

Or you can use one of the built-in `fold`s:

```
fillAll [] = []
fillAll (x:xs) = foldl fill x xs
```

but as Impredicative points out, you'll have better performance with `foldl'` from Data.List

Comment: Is it possible to return true if 2 is present in the last element after fillAll completes its execution on all elements?

Comment: The answer to almost every single programming question beginning with "Is it possible to..." is "yes".  How would you go about getting the last element of a list in Haskell?  How would you compare that element to `2`?  I'm not going to give you the answer because I think it's simple enough that you should put forth the effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: @EricaMaine That would find if `2` is in a list of `Int`s, but it would not be checking if the last element of that list is `2`.  Which are you wanting to do?  Also, having `if <expression> then True else False` can simply be replaced with `<expression>`, the if statement is redundant.  You'd basically be saying `if True then True else False`.

Comment: By last element here I mean what is returned from the fillAll function, i.e, from my example, the list [2,2,2,2,2]. So, I'm just checking whether that list has an element 2. Is this wrong?

Comment: @EricaMaine If all you're wanting to do is check if the output from `fillAll` contains a 2, then yes, you can just use ```2 `elem` fillAll lists```, or with what you have defined `helper2 $ fillAll lists`.

Comment: @EricaMaine If your problem is solved, I would encourage you to accept one of the answers so that future readers don't have to read through the comments to find out which one solved your problem.  In all honesty, both answers to this question are pretty much equivalent, it really doesn't matter which one you pick.